# How to show "read more" link after 3 buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this code, I want to display `show more` link, after 3 buttons:
I know, how to display show more button after x words, but how to display show more link after buttons?

This is my code to display `show more` link after x words, if it helps:

```js
jQuery(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('span.showmore');
    
    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var t = $(this).text();        
        if(t.length < 410) return;
        
        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,410)+'<span>... </span><a href="" class="more">Show More</a>'+
            '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(410,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
        );
        
    }); 
    
    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();        
    });
    
    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 3 HD</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 4 SD</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 6</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video</button>
```

Comment: Your current code assumes that you're dealing with text only. Instead, consider something like `var t = $(this).children();` - that should give you a collection of buttons. You'll need to use slightly more advanced DOM creation methods instead of constructing HTML, but `slice` will still work just fine for getting a subset of the buttons.

Comment: Do you want to `Show More` button after each three or only one time ?

Comment: only 1 time @Mr.Developer

Comment: Then you can use jquery eq() function `$( "buttonplaytrailer." ).eq(2).append('<a>Show More</a>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Easy to do like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "button.playtrailer" ).eq(2).after('<a href="#" id="particular">Show More</a>');//add a unique id to link
  $( "button.playtrailer:gt(2)" ).addClass('hide');
});

$(document).on('click','a#particular',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $('button.playtrailer').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 3 HD</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 4 SD</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 6</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video</button>
```

Comment: please check the edited answer. I made it more simpler.

Comment: It makes other links on the pages disappear, on click

Comment: @Toby  yes,sorry  for that mistake. Corrected that one. Please check now

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function for the task.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "button.playtrailer" ).eq(2).after('<a>Read More</a>');
});
```

Here is an [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9822/)

Answer (score 2):

you can add a show more link after first three buttons using jquery and move the rest of buttons to a div with a class and hide it. Attach an eventlistener to the link which shows hidden buttons.

```js
jQuery(function(){
        var playButtons = $('.playtrailer');
        $(playButtons[2]).after('<a id="show-more" href="#">Show more</a>');
        $(playButtons[2]).after('<div class="more-buttons"></div>');
        for (var i=3; i<playButtons.length; i++){
            $(playButtons[i]).detach();
            $(playButtons[i]).appendTo('.more-buttons');
        }
        $('.more-buttons').hide();
        $("#show-more").click(function(){
            $('.more-buttons').toggle();
            $(this).toggle();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 3 HD</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 4 SD</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 6</button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video</button>
```